# Edit Javascript coming from remote server

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, deobfuscation

I have a page that works a bit differently when I access it on the web, and when I download it (through chrome) and access it locally.

I currently don't know why (The page might be doing it on purpose).

I want to be able to somehow edit the code that the browser receives from the server, so I can add different debug prints and see what is the difference.

Comment: You kinda can't really.  Not short of just downloading the code and modifying it.  The best you can do is identify what parts you want to track and echo those values back, or something.

Comment: This is a very vague question! It all depends on what you have in your page. Is it just HTML or Javascript too. are you using basic Javascript or some File /AJAX APIs too? If you own the file on server why not access it as a file to verify your observation. If you do not own the code then downloading a page via browser will not always download all the required js/css files! So please add more details

Comment: you may not be able to change their javascript but you could always execute your own javascript after their javascript has been run, to change whatever result you need to, it's horribly hacky and horrible advice but certainly possible.

Comment: This sounds like a software recommendation to me, in which case I might recommend [Charles Proxy](http://www.charlesproxy.com/), which lets you replace JavaScript coming from a URL with a JavaScript file from your local machine.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using an extension like [Tamper Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tamper-chrome-extension/hifhgpdkfodlpnlmlnmhchnkepplebkb?hl=en)?

> Tamper Chrome allows you to monitor requests sent by your browser and
>   the responses. You can also modify requests as they go out, and to a
>   limited extent modify the responses (headers, css, javascript or
>   XMLHttpRequest responseText).
>
> See what websites are sending in the background, modify submissions,
>   switch out scripts, alter AJAX responses, Tamper Chrome puts the power
>   of your browser back in your hands.

It sounds like what you're looking for, in terms of being able to intercept requests/responses and modify their contents before processing by the browser.

Disclaimer:
I am not in any way affiliated with this software.  I have not tried using this particular extension although I have used similar types of software before.